# uwsgi start fails but does not log any error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uwsgi

I have set up a uwsgi service on a ubuntu 12.04.

Here is the custom config file I am using:

```
[uwsgi]
# this is the path to the virtualenv
home = /var/www/api/webservice/current/

# this will point to the same file
paste = config:/var/www/api/webservice/production.ini

socket = /tmp/my_api.socket
gid = www-data
uid = www-data
logdate = true
master = true
harakiri = 30
limit-as = 1536
reload-on-as = 1200
no-orphans = true
log-x-forwarded-for = true
threads = 15
workers = 2
stats = /tmp/my_api_stats.socket
listen = 400
```

When I run `sudo service uwsgi start` I get "Fail".
But the log in /var/log/uwsgi/app/my_api.log doesn't show any error message.

How can I debug this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a debug step, you could examine your `ExecStart` command from /etc/systemd/system unit configuration for `uwsgi` service. Try running that command and see, if there is some more information about the error.

By the way, are you sure your logfile `/var/log/uwsgi/app/my_api.log` is the one, where the logs are written to? Of course, that could be default, but if it is not, you should have the `logto=/path/to/the/log` option in your config.

Comment: Brilliant! Turns out my ExecStart was using /etc/uwsgi/sites which my version did not have, so I edited the command to use /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled which is where my ini was.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using debian based linux os, you will find log for you app by default in /var/log/uwsgi/app/log.

I also had hard time, while debugging the reason for the failure of starting of uwsgi service. 
For me `uwsgi --ini this_config_file.ini` worked fine, but `service uwsgi start` was failing without giving much information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `uwsgi --ini this_config_file.ini` will help you debug it?